# Best Out-Of-The-Box Script For News Aggragtor / Crawler

Tags: web-crawler, feed, aggregator

Sorry that there are already several threads on how to build an aggregator. Most of them are helpful in terms of explaining the nuts and bolts of building one, but I just need suggestion on stable and reliable scripts already out there.

I am specifically looking at adding a Fashion-Specific News Aggregator to my Wordpress site dedicated to fashion. In simple terms, I need a script that can crawl the web looking for latest news in websites like Glam, Vogue, Instyle, NYTimes, Fashion, etc. and feed them into different categories I have - Fashion & Style, Beauty & Make Up, Health & Wellness etc.

I just need a few recommendations from fellow stackoverflowers on scripts that can do this (or with little customization). Thanks a ton! And happy holidays everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there won't be any good modules for wordpress. So i recommend that you install a real news aggregator and theme it like your wordpress website.  Like http://planet.wordpress.org/ Unfortunately planet wordpress does not seem to leave credit to the software they use.

[PlanetPlanet](http://planetplanet.org) is a classic in Python, but [Moonmoon](http://moonmoon.org) is in PHP and claims a 2-step installation so it looks easy.